Possible to vectorize date arithmetic with different offset per row?
I have a simple function get_start_of_period which takes in a date and returns the start of that period. It looks as follows:
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from typing import Literal

def get_start_of_period(date: dt.date, term_length: Literal[1, 3, 12]) -> dt.date:
    months_in_period = (date.month - 1) % term_length
    return date - relativedelta(day=1, months=months_in_period)

This function takes any input date and converts it to the beginning of the month, quarter, or year depending on the term_length param:
>>> curr_date = dt.date(2024, 6, 7)
>>> get_start_of_period(curr_date, term_length=1)
datetime.date(2024, 6, 1)
>>> get_start_of_period(curr_date, term_length=3)
datetime.date(2024, 4, 1)
>>> get_start_of_period(curr_date, term_length=12)
datetime.date(2024, 1, 1)

I have a Pandas Series of dates which I would like to convert to the start of their respective period in this manner. You can assume term_length will be constant for the whole Series. Is there a way to vectorize that conversion? Currently I just have this written as a series.apply(lambda curr_date: get_start_of_period(curr_date, term_length=1) but I'm wondering if I can improve that.
The pd.DateOffset appears to only accept a constant, and pd.Timedelta doesn't take month-level granularity. numpy supports a timedelta64[M] object, but the behavior looks odd -- adding a delta of 1 month adds 30 days, while adding n > 1 months adds two months minus a day.
Most solutions I see online appear to use apply, just wondering if we can do one better.
Thank you!

Turns out Pandas has MonthBegin, QuarterBegin, and YearBegin, which do what I need. Think this does the trick:
def get_start_of_period_pd(series: pd.Series, term_length: int) -> pd.Series:
    if term_length == 1:
        end_shift = pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)
        start_shift = pd.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
    elif term_length == 3:
        end_shift = pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(n=0, startingMonth=3)
        start_shift = pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(startingMonth=1)
    else:
        end_shift = pd.offsets.YearEnd(n=0, month=12)
        start_shift = pd.offsets.YearBegin(month=1)

    return series - end_shift - start_shift


I hope it can help you. In base to your information, I understand and make this:
def get_start_of_period(date_series: pd.Series, term_length: int) -> pd.Series:
    """
    Returns the start date of a period based on the given term length.

    Parameters:
    - date_series (pd.Series): A pandas Series containing dates.
    - term_length (int): The length of the term in months. Valid values are 1, 3, or 12.

    Returns:
    - pd.Series: A pandas Series containing the start dates of the periods.

    Raises:
    - ValueError: If an invalid term_length is provided.
    """
    if term_length == 1:
        return pd.to_datetime(date_series.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))
    elif term_length == 3:
        return pd.to_datetime(date_series.dt.to_period('Q').dt.start_time)
    elif term_length == 12:
        return pd.to_datetime(date_series.dt.to_period('Y').dt.start_time)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid term_length. Please use 1, 3, or 12.")

I prove it with a simple sample data an works like you describe
# Example usage:
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', periods=5, freq='M'))
term_length = 12
start_of_periods = get_start_of_period(dates, term_length)
print(start_of_periods)

